# Could FAIR scheduling mode make Spark Streaming jobs that read from different topics running in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I use Spark 2.1 and Kafka 0.9.

> Under fair sharing, Spark assigns tasks between jobs in a “round robin” fashion, so that all jobs get a roughly equal share of cluster resources. This means that short jobs submitted while a long job is running can start receiving resources right away and still get good response times, without waiting for the long job to finish.

According to this if i have multiple jobs from multiple threads in case of spark streaming(one topic from each thread) is it possible that multiple topics can run simultaneously if i have enough cores in my cluster or would it just do a round robin across pools but run only one job at a time ?

Context:

I have two topics T1 and T2, both with one 1 partition. I have configured a pool with scheduleMode to be FAIR. I have 4 cores registered with spark. Now each topic has two actions(hence two jobs - totally 4 jobs across topics) Let's say J1 and J2 are jobs for T1 and J3 and J4 are jobs for topic T2. What spark is doing in FAIR mode is execute J1 J3 J2 J4, but at any time only one job is executing. Now as each topic has only one partition, only once core is being used and 3 are just free. This is something which i don't want. 
Any way i can avoid this ?

Comment: Could you add an example of what you are trying to achieve? The question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

> if i have multiple jobs from multiple threads...is it possible that multiple topics can run simultaneously

Yes. That's the purpose of FAIR scheduling mode.

As you may have noticed, I removed "Spark Streaming" from your question since it does not contribute in any way to how Spark schedules Spark jobs. It does not really matter whether you start your Spark jobs from a "regular" application or Spark Streaming one.

Quoting [Scheduling Within an Application](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) (highlighting mine):

> Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), multiple parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from separate threads.
>
> By default, Spark’s scheduler runs jobs in FIFO fashion. Each job is divided into "stages" (e.g. map and reduce phases), and the **first job gets priority on all available resources while its stages have tasks to launch, then the second job gets priority, etc.**

And then the quote you used to ask the question that should now get clearer.

> it is also possible to configure fair sharing between jobs. Under fair sharing, Spark assigns tasks between jobs in a "round robin" fashion, so that all jobs get a roughly equal share of cluster resources.

So, speaking about Spark Streaming you'd have to configure FAIR scheduling mode and Spark Streaming's JobScheduler should submit Spark jobs per topic in parallel (haven't tested it out myself so it's more theory than practice).

Comment: I have two topics T1 and T2, both with one 1 partition. I have configured a pool with scheduleMode to be FAIR. I have 4 cores registered with spark. Now each topic has two actions(hence two jobs - totally 4 jobs across topics) Let's say J1 and J2 are jobs for T1 and J3 and J4 are jobs for topic T2. What spark is doing in FAIR mode is execute J1 J3 J2 J4, but at any time only one job is executing. Now as  each topic has only one partition, only once core is being used and 3 are just free. This is something which i don't want. Any way i can avoid this ?

Comment: I don't think that the fair scheduler alone will help. This is because, the submission of the jobs needs to be parallelized and in the standard configuration, Spark Streaming will sequence job submissions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that fair scheduler alone will not help, as it's the Spark Streaming engine that takes care of submitting the Spark Jobs and normally does so in a sequential mode.

There's a non-documented configuration parameter in Spark Streaming: `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs`[[1]](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/JobScheduler.scala#L51), which is set to `1` by default. It controls the parallelism level of jobs submitted to Spark.

By increasing this value, you may see parallel processing of the different spark stages of your streaming job.

I would think that combining this configuration with the fair scheduler in Spark, you will be able to achieve controlled parallel processing of the independent topic consumers. This is mostly uncharted territory.

Comment: Yes, i have tried adding spark.streaming.concurrentJobs to my config. The problem here is lets say i set this value to 2 and J1 and J2 both have same transformation which persists in memory(J1 -> T - A1 and J2 -> T - A2). The problem is both jobs get scheduled parallely but both depend on the same transformation to be completed. Hence job J2 will only get completed when Job J1 gets completed(they are not mutually exclusive). Ideal situation would have been if jobs scheduled from different threads got parallelised which sadly doesn't happen. (T -Transformation , A1 - Action 1)

Comment: @SiddhantSrivastava could you add your code to the question? Maybe there are other ways to address this issue.

Comment: @SiddhantSrivastava have you tried to run with multiple threads? I am facing the same thing, where my streaming job consumes from multiple topics but job scheduling is happening sequentially. I wanted to schedule this parallel.  Can you share code snipit?

Comment: @SiddhantSrivastava for this - " The problem is both jobs get scheduled parallely but both depend on the same transformation to be completed. Hence job J2 will only get completed when Job J1 gets completed(they are not mutually exclusive)." Can you tried with cache() after transformation?